# How can this be true? Equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I can't figure out why, unless there is something i'm missing.

$\{ 1, 4, 10, 13,...\} \subseteq \{ x \in  \mathbb Z^+| $ $ x =3n+1 $ for $n = 0, 1,2, 3, ...\}$ but  $ \{ 1, 4, 10, 13,...\} \not\subset \{ x \in  \mathbb Z^+| $ $ x =3n+1 $ for $n = 0, 1,2, 3, ...\}$

**please note $ \subset $ is the symbol for a proper subset **

Comment: Sorry but what is $| \mathbb Z^+|$? the first $|$ is not clear.

Comment: You wrote **exactly** the same expressions in both lines but one with $\,\subset\,$ and the other with $\,\not\subset\,$ . Obviously *at least*  one of them is false, so either you didn't understand the question (for example, which option is true) or else you miscopied something...

Comment: You really need to work on your titles. "Universal set theory" makes little sense here.

Comment: What is $|\Bbb Z^+$?

Comment: I find no problem with what you have written. What is it exactly that you can't understand?

Comment: @Cheeku: So a set can be both a subset, and not a subset? Please note the difference between $\nsubseteq$ and $\subsetneq$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, Sorry! I didn't realize the second was also a part of question. Sorry for that.

Comment: I would venture a guess that there is simply an extra bar in there, and that it should be $\{x\in\Bbb Z^+\mid\dots$

Comment: @Max, in this case, the two sets appear to be equal, so perhaps what you mean is that $A\subseteq B$ but it is not true that $A\subsetneq B$.

Comment: I have corrected the question. Does the $\subset$ and $\subseteq$

Comment: @Max: It still isn't corrent $\subseteq$ implies $\subset$ so $\subseteq$ and $\not\subset$ can't both be true.  Did you mean $\subsetneq$ instead?  The latex for that is \subsetneq.

Comment: @Jim its both $ \not\subset $ and $ \subseteq $

Comment: Part of the problem here is that $\subset$ is ambiguous.  Some people use it to mean $\subseteq$; others use it to mean $\subsetneq$. Presumably, whoever posed this question intends the second meaning.  (Because of the ambiguity, I recommend never using $\subset$.)

Comment: @Max: If you don't mean $\subsetneq$ then the question is incorrect, $\subseteq$ implies $\subset$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass okay, so what does $ \subsetneq $ mean?

Comment: also it says, please note $ \subset $ is the symbol for a proper subset

Answer (score 1):

When we write $\not\subset$ we don't mean "not a proper subset" but rather "not a subset" at all.

This is why I prefer $\subsetneqq$ or $\subsetneq$ for *proper* subset, which can be read as "subset *and* not equal".